# How can I use Siri to send a pre-made SMS?

Tags: messages, sms, text, siri

So I recently discovered that most bus stops have a code.  If you text that code to a specific phone number, you'll get a response telling you the ETA of the next bus to that stop.  I saved the phone number in a contact card and I saved all my frequent bus stop codes stored as a note in that card.

It's a little cumbersome to go into the card, copy the code, open a new text, paste the code, and hit send.  If I remember the code, I can just use Siri and say something like "Tell the bus company 123456".  It's a lot easier to just remember the cross-street names.

Is there a way to either have Siri make a substitution, say for example "Grant Street" with "123456", or else is there a way I could have a canned text all ready to go?  One thought I had would be to create a home screen icon called "Grant Street" that when launched, sends "123456" to the bus company's phone number.  Then I could just say "Launch Grant Street" or something and I'd get back the text saying when the next bus is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are apps that do this, see [Canned](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/canned/id384867159?mt=8).

Really what you need (and I use) is a transit app of some kind. I like [Transit](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/transit-app-now-with-uber!/id498151501?mt=8).

I can't think of a way to get Siri to do this. One workaround is to make keyboard shortcuts so that you type "LGS" and iOS will autocorrect it to "123456".

Comment: I had tried the keyboard shortcut thing and when I use Siri, it doesn't replace the shortcut.  :(  There is a website for the NJ Transit stop time functionality, but it's about 10% reliable whereas the texting thing is about 95% reliable (i.e. text returns an accurate ETA 95% of the time, but their website only yields an accurate time about 10% of the time).  I sent feedback requesting an app be made.  They said they're working on one.  I'll check out Canned & Transit.  Thanks